# Brave web browser not starting, apparmor profile to complain

Tags: browser, ubuntu-dock, apparmor

```
usu@U02:~$ sudo aa-complain /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap.brave.brave 
Profile for /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap.brave.brave not found, skipping
usu@U02:~$ 
usu@U02:~$ sudo aa-complain /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap-update-ns.brave 
Profile for /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap-update-ns.brave not found, skipping
usu@U02:~$
```

however

```
usu@U02:~$ ls -alh /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap*brave*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  62K Jun 25 20:37 /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap.brave.brave
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 438K Jun 25 20:37 /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap-update-ns.brave
usu@U02:~$
```

What's going on?

I am doing that because Brave browser snap app does not start. I believe I was able to start it once directly after installation completion to make some configuration. That's all. All subsequent start attempts fail. I start it from GNOME dock. Ubuntu 18.04 with latest updates installed.

`usysconf' is not present on this Ubuntu nor package manager offers to for installation, however

it is possible to start Brave from command line

```
usu@U02:~$ snap run brave
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gkr-Message: secret service operation failed: An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type="method_call", sender=":1.103" (uid=1000 pid=3622 comm="/snap/brave/59/opt/brave.com/brave/brave         " label="snap.brave.brave (enforce)") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Peer" member="Ping" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.secrets" (uid=1000 pid=1603 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login " label="unconfined")
[3762:3762:0625/225153.096288:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(368)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[3622:3755:0625/225153.305846:ERROR:rewards_service_impl.cc(185)] Failed to read file: /home/biri/snap/brave/59/.config/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Default/ledger_state
[3779:3779:0625/225153.420928:ERROR:ledger_impl.cc(345)] Failed to initialize wallet
[3622:3622:0625/225154.488392:ERROR:CONSOLE(0)] "Fetch API cannot load https://pdfjs.robwu.nl/logpdfjs. Redirects to data: URL are allowed only when mode is "no-cors".", source: chrome-extension://oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm/pdfHandler.html (0)
[3622:3622:0625/225154.488465:ERROR:CONSOLE(0)] "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch", source: chrome-extension://oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm/pdfHandler.html (0)
[3622:3622:0625/225541.304923:ERROR:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: brave_new_tab is not defined", source: chrome://newtab/ (1)
[3622:3622:0625/225548.256027:ERROR:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: brave_new_tab is not defined", source: chrome://settings/ (1)
[3622:3753:0625/225638.475561:ERROR:printer_manager_dialog_linux.cc(83)] Failed to open printer manager dialog 
[3622:3992:0625/225640.690851:ERROR:printer_manager_dialog_linux.cc(83)] Failed to open printer manager dialog 
[3622:3753:0625/225642.535546:ERROR:printer_manager_dialog_linux.cc(83)] Failed to open printer manager dialog 
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
[3622:3622:0625/230002.943704:ERROR:CONSOLE(1247)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'annotationAvailable' of undefined", source: chrome://print/pdf/pdf_viewer.js (1247)
usu@U02:~$
```

It does not suffice to start Brave once from CL, to skip welcome tour than to start from Dock. Every attempt to start from GNOME fails. There is no extensions installed named pdfhandler or so.

Comment: Seems to work now. However unable to tell the version threshold on which it started to work.